# My array is not getting sorted on php

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array reading it from a file. My code executes but the array in the file does not get sorted. any ideas what am I missing ?

```
<?php
$file = fopen("text.txt","at");

$Array = file("text.txt");

rsort($Array);

fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: Hi, do you want to sort array in descending order?

Comment: How do you know? `print_r($Array);`  I hope you don't expect it to be written back to the file with that code.

Answer (score 2):

The code above will sort $Array in memory, but will not write the sorted array back to the file. This will write the sorted output back.

```
file_put_contents("text.txt", $Array)
```

Here is modified code that (with `print_r` statements to illustrate the sort):

```
<?php
$Array = file("text.txt");
print_r($Array);
rsort($Array);
print_r($Array);
file_put_contents("text.txt", $Array);
```

Note that `rsort` will sort descending order. That code will sort the following file:

```
Z
D
A
C
```

to:

```
Z
D
C
A
```

Comment: Thanks. You are write a was only sorting the array in memory but not making the changes on the actual file. Thank you again

Comment: Happy to assist. Please mark the question as answered, if you could!